# Choosing the right resolution in Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, bitmap, sprite, resolution

I'm creating my first 2D-game for Android with Unity3D and I have a target resolution of 1080x1920 (my GUI uses this resolution). Is this resolution too big for a mobile game? I didn't make the in-game-sprites yet and I'm just wondering that the resolution might be too large (memory comsumption).

Should I support two resolutions (1080x1920 and 540x960) or choose a lower one like 720x1280? Do I have to redesign all my GUI-graphics if I choose a resolution like 720x1280? What about the sprites? How do I make the sprites so they look the same in different resolutions?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, when designing any kind of UI, your design should be scale-able. This means that instead of hard coding resolution and image sizes, you should get the resolution programatically, then scale your assets to a percentage of the resolution. To get the resolution in android, I found this code:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

But a lot of the grunt work is still up to you :) With sprite art - it's typically good practice to design your assets in sizes to the power of 2 (16, 32, 64, etc) to best accommodate different resolutions.

Comment: Thanks. But in Unity you use C#.